# How to manually visualize the flow of the recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, recursion

I have an algorithm that generates [partitions](http://I%20am%20asking%20for%20a%20way%20to%20write%20the%20flow%20of%20this%20program%20on%20paper,%20so%20that%20I%20can%20understand%20it%20better.) for a given number. I am asking for a way to write the flow of this program on paper so that I can understand it better.

I'm trying to trace the recursion within a loop in the method below:

```
 public static long calculate(final long totalSum, final long restriction) {
        appendLineToFile("Calculate function called with values: ");
        appendLineToFile("INPUT: totalSum: " + totalSum);
        appendLineToFile("INPUT: restriction: " + restriction);


        if (totalSum <= 1) {
            // recursive stopping condition
            appendLineToFile("==========recursive stopping condition==========");
            return 1;
        }
        long sum = 0;
        for (long k = 1; k <= restriction; k++) {
            appendLineToFile("Loop begins with k: " + k + " and restriction value: " + restriction);
            sum = sum + calculate(totalSum - k, k);
            appendLineToFile("For Ends" + " Sum in loop is: " + sum + " calculate(totalSum - k, k): " + (totalSum - k) + "," + k);

        }
       // appendLineToFile("=======Returning sum: " + sum + "===========");
        return sum;
    }
```

Here is the output for inputs 6 and 3:

```
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 6
INPUT: restriction: 3
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 5
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 4
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 3
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 2
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 1
INPUT: restriction: 1
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 1,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 2,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 3,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 4,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 5,1
Loop begins with k: 2 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 4
INPUT: restriction: 2
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 2
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 3
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 2
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 1
INPUT: restriction: 1
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 1,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 2,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 3,1
Loop begins with k: 2 and restriction value: 2
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 2
INPUT: restriction: 2
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 2
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 1
INPUT: restriction: 1
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 1,1
Loop begins with k: 2 and restriction value: 2
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 0
INPUT: restriction: 2
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 2 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 0,2
For Ends Sum in loop is: 3 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 2,2
For Ends Sum in loop is: 4 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 4,2
Loop begins with k: 3 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 3
INPUT: restriction: 3
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 2
INPUT: restriction: 1
Loop begins with k: 1 and restriction value: 1
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 1
INPUT: restriction: 1
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 1,1
For Ends Sum in loop is: 1 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 2,1
Loop begins with k: 2 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 1
INPUT: restriction: 2
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 2 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 1,2
Loop begins with k: 3 and restriction value: 3
Calculate function called with values: 
INPUT: totalSum: 0
INPUT: restriction: 3
==========recursive stopping condition==========
For Ends Sum in loop is: 3 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 0,3
For Ends Sum in loop is: 7 calculate(totalSum - k, k): 3,3
Result is: 7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For the three initial loops I've written the following by hand:

[image]

Any help on how to traverse this by hand would be highly appreciated

Comment: ... what's the question? Why don't you just ask the computer to print it instead of doing it manually?

Comment: @user202729 sometimes you need to know what the computer is doing. I have inherited this code from a predecessor in my job!

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? What's the problem with it?

Comment: Have you used your IDE debugger to step through the code?  That surely is the easiest way to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, Jim yes I have done that. Its a bit confusing that is why posted here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to ask it again to make it explicit. Are you asking for a way to write down the flow of this algorithm manually on paper? Or do you want us to suggest how to improve your trace output?

Comment: I am asking for a way to write the flow of this program on paper, so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to understand an algorithm if you're walking through it step-by-step writing each action on a separate line.

You can use indentation to visualize the depth of recursive calls.

Here is how I would visualize this particular algorithm:

```
calculate(6,3)   //function call
sum = 0          //assignment
k = 1
    calculate(5,1)        //indentation shows the call hierarchy
    sum = 0
    k = 1
        calculate(4,1)
        sum = 0
        k = 1
            calculate(3,1)         
            sum = 0
            k = 1
                calculate(2,1)
                sum = 0
                k = 1
                    calculate(1,1)
                    return 1          
                sum = 1            //returning back to the caller
                return 1
            sum = 1
            return 1
        sum = 1
        return 1
    sum = 1
    return 1
sum = 1
k = 2
    calculate(4,2)
    ...
```

The output might get lengthy for larger inputs, but this approach makes it easier to look through recursive calls.

By the way, you don't actually need to write all of this by hand. It's relatively easy to add `depth` parameter to your method:

```
calculate(final long totalSum, final long restriction, int depth) {
     ....
     sum = sum + calculate(totalSum - k, k, depth+1);
```

Then you can create a method to output the line with proper indentation:

```
appendIndentedLine(depth, "calculate("+totalSum+....
```

I'll leave the implementation of `appendIndentedLine` for you as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking out time and giving this elegant solution. Youve made my day.

Comment: You have a great day ahead Sir!!